# Gaming on Ubuntu touch

Tags: application-development, games, ubuntu-touch

I am an indie game developer who is interested in targeting Ubuntu and Ubuntu Touch. I have noticed that you support various tools. I am wondering if you support OpenGL and how much tweaking does a game need to have in order to run properly on Ubuntu? I know that you have different layouts(tablet, phone, pc, tv) and I am wondering how would that effect the game development. Finally, my game  runs on several platforms such as OpenGL, Android, HTML5, Flash. Which one of these is the best to target Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I am not a developer myself, but I know Ubuntu supports OpenGL, Adobe Flash Player and HTML5. Ubuntu does not support Adobe Shockwave, as Adobe does not bother to create a package for Linux.

My opinion would be to go with OpenGL as that usually has good performance with Ubuntu. You probably already know that Flash is limiting, buggy, and has performance problems. I'm not sure about HTML5 as that hasn't gone mainstream yet, but I'm hoping that it will overtake and replace Flash.

Hope this gives you an idea on what to go for.

Comment: I guess HTML5 has pretty much taken over by now.